# Scroll views under collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, user-interface, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I would like to create UI screen the same as twitter profile.

I want views scroll under collapsing toolbar but toolbar be pinned. I've tried to change `scrollFlags` of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `scroll` but then toolbar disappears while scrolling. If I add flags as `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` then `LinearLayout` is not scrolled under toolbar. Also I want `TabLayout` to be sticky.

Any advice?

https://i.imgur.com/XCleWyY.gif

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userInfoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NickName"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```